# Why doesn't this code produce torn reads?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, clr, atomic

When going through the CLR/CLI specs and memory models etc, I noticed the wording around atomic reads/writes according to the [ECMA CLI spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm):

> A conforming CLI shall guarantee that read and write access to
>   properly aligned memory locations no larger than the native word size
>   (the size of type native int) is atomic when all the write accesses to
>   a location are the same size.

Specifically the phrase '*properly aligned memory*' caught my eye. I wondered if I could somehow get torn reads with a `long` type on a 64-bit system with some trickery. So I wrote the following test-case:

```
unsafe class Program {
    const int NUM_ITERATIONS = 200000000;
    const long STARTING_VALUE = 0x100000000L + 123L;
    const int NUM_LONGS = 200;
    private static int prevLongWriteIndex = 0;

    private static long* misalignedLongPtr = (long*) GetMisalignedHeapLongs(NUM_LONGS);

    public static long SharedState {
        get {
            Thread.MemoryBarrier();
            return misalignedLongPtr[prevLongWriteIndex % NUM_LONGS];
        }
        set {
            var myIndex = Interlocked.Increment(ref prevLongWriteIndex) % NUM_LONGS;
            misalignedLongPtr[myIndex] = value;
        }
    }

    static unsafe void Main(string[] args) {
        Thread writerThread = new Thread(WriterThreadEntry);
        Thread readerThread = new Thread(ReaderThreadEntry);

        writerThread.Start();
        readerThread.Start();

        writerThread.Join();
        readerThread.Join();

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static IntPtr GetMisalignedHeapLongs(int count) {
        const int ALIGNMENT = 7;
        IntPtr reservedMemory = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(new IntPtr(sizeof(long) * count + ALIGNMENT - 1));
        long allocationOffset = (long) reservedMemory % ALIGNMENT;
        if (allocationOffset == 0L) return reservedMemory;
        return reservedMemory + (int) (ALIGNMENT - allocationOffset);
    }

    private static void WriterThreadEntry() {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; ++i) {
            SharedState = STARTING_VALUE + i;
        }
    }

    private static void ReaderThreadEntry() {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; ++i) {
            var sharedStateLocal = SharedState;
            if (sharedStateLocal < STARTING_VALUE) Console.WriteLine("Torn read detected: " + sharedStateLocal);
        }
    }
}
```

However, no matter how many times I run the program I never legitimately see the line "Torn read detected!". So why not?

I allocated multiple `long`s in a single block in the hopes that at least one of them would spill between two cache lines; and the 'start point' for the first `long` should be misaligned (unless I'm misunderstanding something).

Also I know that the nature of multithreading errors means they can be hard to force, and that my 'test program' isn't as rigorous as it could be, but I've run the program almost 30 times now with no results- each with 200000000 iterations.

Comment: Describe *exactly* the sequence of events you believe would produce the message in this program.

Comment: In the writer loop, I believe I'm writing a 64-bit value to some place in memory- each time a slightly different place but wherever it is it ought to be aligned on a 7-byte boundary (e.g. misaligned- I think). Because I'm writing to 200 64-bit values I'm confident that at least one of them should cross a cache-line boundary too (not sure if this matters). Because of the stipulation in the CLI about memory accesses only being atomic if they are aligned, I'm assuming that my `long` writes are not atomic anymore. Then I'm hoping that the reader thread will catch one of those writes 'in action'.

Comment: What does crossing a cache line have to do with anything?

Comment: I actually added the cache line stuff later on after I didn't get the result I was looking for the first time around- but like I said I wasn't really sure it was necessary. I should point out that I've asked this question because I'm unsure on a few concepts around all the things it touches- so sorry if I'm leading you along a wild goose chase in places.

Comment: You need to describe the situation at a far lower level than that. You're waving your hands and saying "this should be non-atomic", but pick a specific memory address, and pick a specific ordering of reads and writes, and describe what sequence of reads and writes leads to a tear in your program. I don't see any such sequence but you must have one in mind.

Comment: Firstly I'm trying to create a `long*` that is an array of `long`s "misaligned" in `GetMisalignedHeapLongs`. From what I understand of CPUs a misaligned write is not atomic by default. When the loop in `WriterThreadEntry` writes to `SharedState` it first increments `prevLongWriteIndex` and *then* actually writes `value` in the appropriate place in my `long` 'array'. I'm expecting to occasionally see a simultaneous attempt to read from that place as it's being written via `SharedState`'s getter because `prevLongWriteIndex` is already updated to point at the write target before writing happens.

Comment: The simultaneous read I expect to be torn because the write, I was assuming, should be nonatomic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of flaws in this program that hides torn reads.  Reasoning about the behavior of unsynchronized threads is never simple, and hard to explain, the odds for *accidental* synchronization are always high.

```
  var myIndex = Interlocked.Increment(ref prevLongWriteIndex) % NUM_LONGS;
```

Nothing very subtle about Interlocked, unfortunately it affects the reader thread a great deal as well.  Pretty hard to see, but you can use Stopwatch to time the execution of the threads.  You'll see that Interlocked on the writer slows down the reader by a factor of ~2.  Enough to affect the timing of the reader and not repro the problem, accidental synchronization.

Simplest way to eliminate the hazard and maximize the odds of detecting a torn read is to just always read and write from the same memory location.  Fix:

```
  var myIndex = 0;
```

---

```
  if (sharedStateLocal < STARTING_VALUE)
```

This test doesn't help much to detect torn reads, there are many that simply don't trigger the test.  Having too many binary zeros in the STARTING_VALUE make it extra unlikely.  A good alternative that maximizes the odds for detection is to alternate between 1 and -1, ensuring the byte values are always different and making the test very simple.  Thus:

```
private static void WriterThreadEntry() {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; ++i) {
        SharedState = 1;
        SharedState = -1;
    }
}

private static void ReaderThreadEntry() {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; ++i) {
        var sharedStateLocal = SharedState;
        if (Math.Abs(sharedStateLocal) != 1) {
            Console.WriteLine("Torn read detected: " + sharedStateLocal);
        }
    }
}
```

---

That quickly gets you several pages of torn reads in the console in 32-bit mode.  To get them in 64-bit as well you need to do extra work to get the variable mis-aligned.  It needs to straddle the L1 cache-line boundary so the processor has to perform two reads and writes, like it does in 32-bit mode.  Fix:

```
private static IntPtr GetMisalignedHeapLongs(int count) {
    const int ALIGNMENT = -1;
    IntPtr reservedMemory = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(new IntPtr(sizeof(long) * count + 64 + 15));
    long cachelineStart = 64 * (((long)reservedMemory + 63) / 64);
    long misalignedAddr = cachelineStart + ALIGNMENT;
    if (misalignedAddr < (long)reservedMemory) misalignedAddr += 64;
    return new IntPtr(misalignedAddr);
}
```

Any ALIGNMENT value between -1 and -7 will now produce torn reads in 64-bit mode as well.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer Hans. May I ask why you add 15 'spare' bytes of memory to the allocation instead of 8? Even if the difference between `reservedMemory` and `cachelineStart` is 63 bytes, we'd only need a maximum of  `sizeof(long)` (8) bytes additional 'spare' room to store the actual values?

Comment: Oh wait, is it because `AllocHGlobal` allocates on an 8-byte boundary; so the '15' comes from `(sizeof(long) - 1) + 8`?

Comment: Yes.  I wanted to also try positive ALIGNMENT values up to 7.

Comment: I just tried it with ALIGNMENT set to 3. Whereas on -3 I get torn reads, on positive 3 I get no such thing. Which makes sense to me, as you're no longer straddling a cache line right?